# PHP - Check twitter response and error code

Tags: php, twitter

Im using the TwitterOauth library to post to Twitter ([https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/))

Im using the following line to post:

```
$oauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));
```

How can I fetch the reponse that comes back from twitter using PHP, I want to check the response has a `200` server message indicating a successful post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $serverResponse = $oauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));
 print_r($serverResponse);
```

fairly certain you'll get some good info outta there...!

Answer (score 0):

`$response = $oauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));`